# C# byte* to VB.NET BitmapData scanline

Tags: c#, vb.net, pointers, byte

how do I convert C# code

bmd is BitmapData

```
 byte* scanline = (byte*)bmd.Scan0 + (y * bmd.Stride);
```

to VB.NET?

Online C# to VB.net converter gave me this line

```
Dim scanline As Pointer(Of Byte) = CType(bmd.Scan0, Pointer(Of Byte)) + (y * bmd.Stride)
```

> but Type 'Pointer' is not defined. in
>   VB.Net?

What are my options?, thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marshal is the only way here. I've done this before with much success, but it was anoying.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.scan0.aspx

```
' Get the address of the first line.
Dim ptr As IntPtr = bmpData.Scan0

' Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
' This code is specific to a bitmap with 24 bits per pixels.
Dim bytes As Integer = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height
Dim rgbValues(bytes - 1) As Byte

' Copy the RGB values into the array.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes)
```

Comment: How do I exactly solve my problem? I got this atm                 Dim scanline(bmd.Width * PIXLESIZE) As Byte

                Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmd.Scan0, scanline, (y * bmd.Stride), bmd.Width * PIXLESIZE) but it fails after one pass.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers are not supported in VB.NET.  The alternatives are unpleasantly slow as long as VB.NET is your requirement, the Marshal class is all you got.  It shouldn't have to be, adding a C# class library to your solution and using its classes in your VB.NET code is very well supported in Visual Studio.

Comment: very funny as the way I see it, .NET framework is a huge system which is wrapped by many implmentations such as Delphi.NET/C#/VB.. so they should all have the same functionality.. I guess VB.NET tries to be as bare as possible to represent being BASIC langauge. although under the hood all languages do the same code? maybe i'm wrong here.. but I install one .NET framework for all languages =P

Comment: Support for writing unsafe code isn't common in languages that got ported to .NET.  F#, IronPython, IronRuby, JScript don't have it either for example.  Etcetera.  Buy the C# team a cigar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got exactly but it fails after one pass. Something about the array being out of bounds probably something with the y*bmd.Stride (but i don't understand why a out of bounds error occurs there as it should just copy raw memory bytes no arrays are used!)

```
  Public Function findImages(ByVal bmd As BitmapData) As List(Of Point)
    Dim results As New List(Of Point)()
    foundRects = New List(Of Rectangle)()

    For y As Integer = 0 To bmd.Height - 1
        'oringinal code
        'Dim scanline As Pointer(Of Byte) = CType(bmd.Scan0, Pointer(Of Byte)) + (y * bmd.Stride)

        'mess is here
        ' gets address of the first line
        'Dim ptr As IntPtr = bmd.Scan0
        'Dim bytes As Integer = (y * bmd.Stride)
        'If bytes = 0 Then bytes = bmd.Stride
        Dim scanline(bmd.Width * PIXLESIZE) As Byte

        'Copy the RGB values into the array.
        Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmd.Scan0, scanline, (y * bmd.Stride), bmd.Width * PIXLESIZE)
        ' --------------------------------

        For x As Integer = 0 To bmd.Width - 1
            Dim xo As Integer = x * PIXLESIZE
            Dim buff As Byte() = {scanline(xo), scanline(xo + 1), scanline(xo + 2), &HFF}
            Dim val As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(buff, 0)

            ' Pixle value from subimage in desktop image
            If pixels.ContainsKey(val) AndAlso notFound(x, y) Then
                Dim loc As Point = DirectCast(pixels(val), Point)

                Dim sx As Integer = x - loc.X
                Dim sy As Integer = y - loc.Y
                ' Subimage occurs in desktop image 
                If imageThere(bmd, sx, sy) Then
                    Dim p As New Point(x - loc.X, y - loc.Y)
                    results.Add(p)
                    foundRects.Add(New Rectangle(x, y, bmImage.Width, bmImage.Height))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Return results
End Function
```

Comment: Is it because you're setting the copy array offset to "(y * bmd.Stride)"? I set this to 0 and the loop works ok... (just that part, not the actual workhorse area of your code, some of the other stuff is missing). Also use the bit "bytes = (y * bmd.Stride)" and declare scanline as Dim scanline(bytes - 1)

Comment: the way I see it is that Scan0 is the pointer to the data correct so in the original C# code (scan0+(y*Stride)) = start of next line of pixel data. meaning scan0+(0*Stride) same as scan0+0 (no change) = first line so lets say Stride = 5120. it becomes scan0+5120 = next line etc.. the scanline always holds the length of one line. meaning the WIDTH of the image times 4 (pixelsize) because one pixel is 4 bytes of data. I've used the commented lines it didn't work properly so I attempted to remake it bmd.Width*PixelSize is always the size of scanline so it shouldn't overflow/out of bounds anything

Comment: Maybe i was ment to do something like this                 Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmd.Scan0+(y * bmd.Stride), scanline, 0, bmd.Width * PIXLESIZE)  Is that possible?

Comment: ah i see it's only possible in Framework v4.0 i don't want to install that one though http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.add.aspx

Comment: Solved =]                  Dim scanline((bmd.Width * PIXLESIZE) - 1) As Byte
                Dim scanlinea As IntPtr = New IntPtr(bmd.Scan0.ToInt32 + (y * bmd.Stride))
                'Copy the RGB values into the array.
                Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(scanlinea, scanline, 0, bmd.Width * PIXLESIZE)

Comment: thanks good luck with your own projects as well, this is a hobby project hehe making a Tetris Autoplaying bot.